# Wordpress mangles all URLs to invalid corrupt URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress site on my server 192.168.0.1 for testing purposes.

Only the base HTML renders without images.

On examining source, I can see why: all URLs are severely mangled. Instead of referencing

```
http://192.168.0.1/...
```

to find .js, .jpg, etc. files, Wordpress is using

```
http://192.168.0.1192.168.0.1/...
```

or even

```
http://192.168.0.1192.168.0.1192.168.0.1/...
```

Why is WordPress repeating the base URL twice (or sometimes thrice) for all http links it renders?

This is after Wordpress was moved from my live to my testing server by updating siteurl and home in wp_options and editing wp_config.php.

I want to just set up a testing server where I can test upgrades, as PHP 7.2 completely breaks my plugin mix and I need to test / debug first before rolling out on live.

But I cannot get my WP instance to run at all on my testing server due to this "url mangling" taking place.

(My admin backend is also broken, cannot log into it as WP also rewrites its 192.168.0.1/wp-admin/index.php URL into 192.168.0.1192.168.0.1/wp-admin/index.php, which doesn't exist / is invalid.)

ANY ideas or suggestions appreciated!

Thx

Stefan

Comment: can you please check how you set the url for .js, .jpg etc files? there might be issue with file url setup by code. might be you use somethings like '/siteurl/....' like this.

Comment: Hi Nidhi

Thx for the reply.

That's the problem, I do not manually set anything that I'm aware of.

The mangled links are all auto-generated HTTP links to various images used by the theme, included .js files from plugins, etc.

The mangling is consistent across the WP core, the theme, and all plugins.

Comment: can you check your siteurl ? If you have access of database then please check in database. of add your siteurl in the config.php file. or contact to server support for set your site url. As you say your admin backend redirect to the broken url so more changes for the issue of siteurl.

Comment: Ok, I've set siteurl and home in both wp-config.php and the wp_options table to

192.168.0.1/

e.g. add the slash at the end.

No effect, the site is still referencing

http://192.168.0.1192.168.0.1192.168.0.1/

Comment: Deactivate that plugin and check if plugin issue then you need to change plugin. If no plugin issue then please ask in server support might be server site pointing issue also possible.

Comment: Ok I tried that it helped a little...

Instead of the URLs being mangled like this 192.168.0.1192.168.0.1192.168.0.1

they are now mangled like this

192.168.0.1/192.168.0.1/...

with the offending plugin disabled by renaming its folder in wp-content/plugins... e.g. the "hostname" now repeats twice with a slash in the middle.

Comment: can you check .htaccess file and permalink settings?

Comment: I have removed the .htaccess file by renaming it to .htaccess.bak. I cannot access permalink settings as the back-end is also being effected, trying to access 192.168.0.1/wp-admin/index.php results in 192.168.0.1192.168.0.1192.168.0.1/... and a 404 error.